# VBA to copy certain column from active row, copy and paste if cell value multiple times

Tags: vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHs9X.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWaOS.jpg)I am a newbie to VBA. I want Excel to (1) copy cells A:Z of the active row, (2) insert one row below the active row, and paste the values of the recently copied cells into the new blank row.

i have two different values in B Column, then I make two lines same value and update B cell value in second values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWaOS.jpg)

I will appreciate being taught how to only copy certain cells of active row to paste below. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyInsertPaste()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim RowNum As Integer

RowNum = ActiveCell.Row

Set Rng = Range("A" & RowNum & ":Z" & RowNum)

With Rng
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    .Copy Range("A" & RowNum + 1)
End With

Dim BCell1 As Range
Set BCell1 = Range("B" & RowNum)

Dim BCell2 As Range
Set BCell2 = Range("B" & RowNum + 1)

    If InStr(BCell1.Value, ",") Then
        Dim Text1 As String
        Text1 = Left(BCell1.Value, InStr(1, BCell1.Value, ",") - 1)
        BCell1.Value = Text1
                
        Dim index As Integer
        index = InStr(1, BCell2.Value, ",")
        
        Dim Text2 As String
        Text2 = Right(BCell2.Value, Len(BCell2.Value) - index)
        BCell2.Value = Text2
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Parick, but my requirement is, in some cases, we have two values in B cells. Thus, we Manually make two rows of multivalued rows and keep each value separately.

**Fin Co.** **MEP Code**
2258      PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258, MFG_DUNF_5EX_2258
2258     PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258
2258     PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258, MFG_DUNF_5EX_2233
2258     PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258
2258     PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258
2258     PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258

Comment: if there are two values in any row of the B column, make them twice, keep one value each. I am unable to share a picture here, this is my requirements.
'MEP Code'
PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258, MFG_DUNF_5EX_2258
PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258
PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258, MFG_DUNF_5EX_2233
PCBA_DUNF_5EX_2258

Comment: Hi Raj. If my revised answer has solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks you.